# What is the word-formation process of "phrasibuler" ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, verbes, néologismes

What would be the words in the formation process of the neologism "phrasibuler" ?

I found this neological verb in this sentence by Céline (*Bagatelles pour un massacre*, 1937):

> la critique, évidemment, donne à fond (elle n'existe que dans ce but, pour cet office) insiste, encense, pontifie, acclame, proclame... **Phrasibule** d'or toutes ces vessies.

I can tell, for sure, that one of the words in the formation process of "phrasibuler" is "phrase", but in order to understand the stylistical effect intended by the author, I wonder what would be the other word, that resonates with "ibule".

Comment: phrase + fabuler peut faire phrasibuler. It is not straightforward. To make it pronounceable, it could be that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native French speaker who hadn't read this word before, I intuitively give it the meaning “to make sentences that are somewhat pompous and are not as interesting or important as their authors believe”.

*-(i)buler* is not a common or productive suffix. I'm not counting *-i-* as part of the suffix because it's a natural faux-Latin back-formation from *phrase*: many Latin roots have a weak *e/i* ending that becomes *i* when there's a following consonant (such as in the suffix *-(i)ble* indicating possibility) but is omitted altogether when it's at the end of the root. The only suffix that's truly recognizable here is *-er*, which is a generic verb suffix. In other words where it occurs, the *-bul-* part is part of the root (*(af)fabuler* < Lat. *fabula*, *déambuler* < Lat. *ambulare*, *tabuler* < Lat. *tabula* are the only common verbs with a root ending like this).

None of these words are close enough to make *phrasibuler* appear as a compound of *phrase* and another word. The word does however vaguely remind me of *[volubile](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/volubile)* (loquacious). So someone who *phrasibule* probably talks a lot, but what they say may be uninteresting or garbled. I'm also reminded of *[patibulaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/patibulaire)*, an adjective which means that a person looks like a criminal, so the words of someone who *phrasibule* are probably to be condemned.

I'm also reminded of a later nonsense word *zibule*¹. (By humorists [Pierre Dac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Dac) and [Francis Blanche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Blanche) in the 1960s, part of a joke about *cintre à zibule*. *Cintre* is a clothes hanger. “*À zibule*” can either be parsed as *Zibule* being the inventor of the hanger — Zibule's clothes hanger — or *zibule* being an accessory of the hanger — originally the hook part, but it can refer to the horizontal bar among younger generation.). I don't know why the word was chosen, but it's an example of the sonority *-ibule* working well for a nonsense word.

Making a verb more complex than it should be, with a pejorative result, is a rare but not isolated phenomenon in French. I'm reminded of the suffix *-coter* which can indicate that something is more complex than it should be, found naturally in *[tricoter](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tricoter)* (knitting, with a common figurative meaning of constructing something complex, often in a pejorative way) and in deliberate coinages such as *[emberlificoter](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/emberlificoter)* and *[tarabiscoté](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tarabiscot%C3%A9)*.

Comment: Wow ! Merci infiniment pour votre réponse !

Answer (score 2):

The only verb in `-ibuler` I know is *[démantibuler](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9mantibuler)*.

Otherwise, there are not that much words with the `-ibule` ending:

[mandibule](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mandibule)
[vestibule](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vestibule)
[fibule](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fibule) (a rare word, but a *fibule* can be made of gold)

In *phrasibuler*, after *phrase*, we also hear *[bulle](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bulle)*.

Comment: Within my household, we have a verb opposite to *démantibuler:* *REMANTIBULER*. Though sometimes quite challenging, it can however also be very rewarding to remantibuler something ;-)

Comment: Dans phrasibuler, on entend aussi buller (Familier : ne rien faire), et ce n'est peut-être pas un hasard!

Comment: @XouDo J'y ai pensé mais ce sens serait un anachronisme ici.

Comment: Ah ok, comme il n'était nulle part indiqué de quand datait l'ouvrage... mais j'aurais du me douter que c'était du Céline.